# Eliminar los caracteres en dos cadenas si el caracter coincide con la cadena

Tags: java, string

Tengo un problema con **Java** y es el siguiente:

Tengo estos dos `String`:

```
String string1 = "aabcdef";
String string2 = "abcghi";
```

Y necesito obtener esto **"adefghi"**.

```
public static String regenerate(String a, String b)
{
      String common = null;

      common = a.replaceAll("[" + b + "]", "");
      common += b.replaceAll("[" + a + "]", "");

      return common;
}
```

Donde lo que quiero hacer es:

**a <strike>abc</strike> def**

**<strike>abc</strike> ghi**

dejando solo: **a def ghi**

Mi problema es que esto me imprime **"defghi"**, que es un resultado erróneo, alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Si quieres eliminar los caracteres repetidos en ambos `String`, creo que tu método funciona bien, elimina `a, b` y `c` que son los caracteres repetidos en ambos `String`

Comment: `defghi`  es lo correcto, según has planteado la pregunta, mientras que `adefghi`sería incorrecto, puesto que `a` se encuentra en ambas cadenas, sólo que en `string1` está dos veces. Si lo que quieres es quitar los caracteres **repetidos una sola vez en ambas cadenas**, entonces debes cambiar el planteamiento de la pregunta.

Comment: @DavidDPG Bien, pregunta editada lo que quiero es obtener **"adefghi"**

Comment: @A.Cedano Bien, pregunta editada lo que quiero es obtener **"adefghi"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta es la respuesta que necesitas, puedes probarlo directamente:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String a = "aabcdef";
        String b = "abcghi";
        System.out.println(regenerate(a,b));
        //Thread.sleep(10000000);
    }

    public static String regenerate(String a, String b)
    {
        HashSet<String> yaRetiradas = new HashSet<>();
        for(String letra : a.split("(?!^)")){
            if(!yaRetiradas.contains(letra) && b.contains(letra)){
                a = a.replaceFirst(letra,"");
                b = b.replaceFirst(letra,"");
                yaRetiradas.add(letra);
            }
        }
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

Vamos quitando caracteres elemento a elemento y comprobamos que esa letra no se haya retirado ya antes. Quitamos solo los elementos repetidos una sola vez en ambas cadenas.

El resultado es **adefghi**.